# ROS on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: beagleboard, ros

Which Robot operating System (ROS) distribution can be installed on Beagle Bone Black with Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 7):

ROS on  Ubuntu supports armhf and arm64 as well as the amd64 architecture. There is a ROS release every year in May. Every ROS release will be supported on exactly one Ubuntu LTS. ROS releases will drop support for EOL (End Of Life) Ubuntu distributions, even if the ROS release is still supported. The ROS Kinetic release is currently supported only on Ubuntu 16.04. ROS Noetic is slated to be the last ROS 1 release, and officially will not support anything beyond Ubuntu 20.04.

The following ROS 2 releases are currently available.

- Released in May 2022, ROS 2 Humble is a Long Term Support (LTS) release with extended support until May, 2027. This makes it a good choice for projects requiring stability and long-term use.
- ROS 2 Iron is the newest ROS 2 release, launched on May 23, 2023. Its End-of-Life (EOL) is expected in November, 2024 since it's a normal release with a shorter term of support of 1.5 years.

---

### ROS installation in Ubuntu 22.04 and later

ROS Noetic is slated to be the last ROS 1 release, and officially will not support anything beyond Ubuntu 20.04. To install ROS 2 in Ubuntu 22.04 and later run the following commands.

1. To install ROS 2 in Ubuntu 22.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
```

2. Add the ROS 2 repository to your software sources.

```
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

3. Install ROS 2 packages.

   ROS 2 packages are built on frequently updated Ubuntu systems. It is always recommended that you ensure your system is up to date before installing new packages. Choose from the following options for installing ROS 2 packages.

   - Desktop install (Recommended): ROS, RViz, demos, tutorials

     ```
     sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop
     ```
   - ROS-Base install (Bare Bones): Communication libraries, message packages, command line tools. No GUI tools.

     ```
     sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-base
     ```
   - Development tools: Compilers and other tools to build ROS packages

     ```
     sudo apt install ros-dev-tools
     ```

#### ROS Noetic installation in Ubuntu 20.04

1. Configure your Ubuntu repositories to allow *restricted*, *universe* and *multiverse*.
2. Run these commands:

   ```
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'  
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
    sudo apt update
   ```
3. Select one of four default ROS configurations.

   ```
    sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full # full desktop
    sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop # desktop install
    sudo apt install ros-noetic-ros-base # no GUI
    sudo apt install ros-noetic-PACKAGE # individual package installation
   ```

   To find available packages, use: `apt-cache search ros-melodic` and then replace `PACKAGE` in `ros-melodic-PACKAGE` by one of the available packages found by `apt-cache search ros-melodic`
4. Initialize `rosdep`. `rosdep` enables you to easily install system dependencies for source you want to compile and is required to run some core components in ROS.

   ```
    sudo rosdep init
    rosdep update
   ```
5. Environment setup

   ```
    echo "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc  
    source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Get `rosinstall`. `rosinstall` enables you to easily download many source trees for ROS packages with one command.

   ```
    sudo apt install python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential
   ```
7. To test your installation, visit the official [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

<sub>**Source:** [Ubuntu install of ROS Kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu), [Ubuntu install of ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu), [Ubuntu install of ROS Noetic](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu)</sub>

---

#### ROS Melodic installation in Ubuntu 18.04

1. Configure your Ubuntu repositories to allow *restricted*, *universe* and *multiverse*.
2. Run these commands:

   ```
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'  
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
    sudo apt update
   ```
3. Select one of four default ROS configurations.

   ```
    sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full # full desktop
    sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop # desktop install
    sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-base # no GUI
    sudo apt install ros-melodic-PACKAGE # individual package installation
   ```

   To find available packages, use: `apt-cache search ros-melodic` and then replace `PACKAGE` in `ros-melodic-PACKAGE` by one of the available packages found by `apt-cache search ros-melodic`
4. Initialize `rosdep`. `rosdep` enables you to easily install system dependencies for source you want to compile and is required to run some core components in ROS.

   ```
    sudo rosdep init
    rosdep update
   ```
5. Environment setup

   ```
    echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc  
    source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Get `rosinstall`. `rosinstall` enables you to easily download many source trees for ROS packages with one command.

   ```
    sudo apt install python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential
   ```
7. To test your installation, visit the official [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

---

#### ROS Kinetic installation in Ubuntu 16.04

1. Configure your Ubuntu repositories to allow *restricted*, *universe* and *multiverse*.
2. Run these commands:

   ```
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'  
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116  
    sudo apt update
   ```
3. Select one of four default ROS configurations.

   ```
    sudo apt install ros-kinetic-desktop-full # full desktop
    sudo apt install ros-kinetic-desktop # desktop install
    sudo apt install ros-kinetic-ros-base # no GUI
    sudo apt install ros-kinetic-PACKAGE # individual package installation
   ```

   To find available packages, use: `apt-cache search ros-kinetic` and then replace `PACKAGE` in `ros-kinetic-PACKAGE` by one of the available packages found by `apt-cache search ros-kinetic`
4. Initialize `rosdep`. `rosdep` enables you to easily install system dependencies for source you want to compile and is required to run some core components in ROS.

   ```
    sudo rosdep init
    rosdep update
   ```
5. Environment setup

   ```
    echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc  
    source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Get `rosinstall`. `rosinstall` enables you to easily download many source trees for ROS packages with one command.

   ```
    sudo apt install python-rosinstall
   ```
7. To test your installation, visit the official [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

Comment: Thank you Karel, I followed the steps and successfully installed ROS-Desktop. However, I couldn't install the 'full' version. I guess some of the packages are not yet available.

Comment: A problem installing ros-kinetic-desktop-full in Ubuntu 16.04 was also reported in this question: [Dependency issue after upgrading to xenial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779938/dependency-issue-after-upgrading-to-xenial) -- `dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-desktop-full (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`