# ROS melodic instalation for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, python3, ros

A lot of packages are still not supported in ros noetic, so i was trying to build melodic from source in ubuntu 20.04. While following instructions from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source), i got stuck in this command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y`

The errors i got were:-

`ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
laser_geometry: No definition of [python-numpy] for OS version [focal]
genpy: No definition of [python-yaml] for OS version [focal]
gencpp: No definition of [python-setuptools] for OS version [focal]
python_orocos_kdl: No definition of [python-sip] for OS version [focal]`

I understand that these are because ubuntu 20.04 doesnt have python in it. So i tried doing

1. `alias python=python3` in my bashrc
2. `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10`

but i still receive these errors. How to resolve these issues? Even if i `sudo apt-get install` all these packages, still these erros are present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ROS on BeagleBone Black?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816178/ros-on-beaglebone-black)

Comment: @karel Actually no. I am trying to install ROS melodic which is unsupported on ubuntu 20.04. I tried following the commands for melodic on ubuntu 18.04 but even after resolving keys, there is no ros-melodic installation component. Thanks

Comment: That's because ROS melodic is unsupported on 20.04. Each Ubuntu LTS has a matching ROS LTS version. For 20.04 it is noetic, not melodic. If you need melodic then install Ubuntu 18.04 in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks. On an unrelated note, can i have Virtual Machine inside ubunut 20.04 running ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You most certainly can.

Comment: Using KVM? Do i have to do something more?

Comment: KVM is very nice. That's what I use.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into that

Answer (score 1):

Towards answering your question...

I began down the path suggested by @HimnashuTanwar, building melodic from source, but ultimately concluded that a full ros melodic install is not viable in 20.04.

A few notes:

- Adding a -r to the rosdep command immediately exposed all of the
  dependencies related to Python2 Most such dependencies could be met
  `using pip install -U [package]`.
- A notable exception was pyqt5, which in turn depended on sip.  At first I endeavored to build the sources of these two, as per https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source, but settled on this solution instead: [How to get PyQt5 for Python2 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254347/how-to-get-pyqt5-for-python2-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- What caused me to abandon the build was a nasty dependence of
  melodic's tf2 on an earlier version of Boost.  It turns out that 20.04 runs on libboost1.71, wherein boost-signals has been deprecated and deleted, and this breaks the build of tf2 -- this issue is of course remedied in Noetic.

So in the end, it's probably best to stick with the supported version pairs: melodic on 18.04 or noetic on 20.04+, as per (http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bsh
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic --os=ubuntu:bionic -y
```

Apart from that, melodic uses python2, which isn't in focal. So install python2, pip and other dependencies. After that, `update-alternatives` to python2 and pip2.

I haven't tried it yet; you may comment for further problems.