# Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full

Tags: software-installation, ros

I tried to install the ROS-NOETIC package on Ubuntu 22.04, but I got an error as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

I'm new to Ubuntu. Please support me in this issue. Thank You.

Comment: That means that with that there is no official Ubuntu package. Try `apt-cache search ros`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ROS on BeagleBone Black?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816178/ros-on-beaglebone-black)