# How do i get rid of this error, I get this error whenever I try use sudo apt update!

Tags: ros

[image]

So this is the error I get whenever I try to use `sudo apt update` on my terminator

Comment: ROS 1 is still stuck on 20.04. Either reinstall an older Ubuntu, or upgrade to ROS 2, which targets 22.04.

Comment: Providing the text copied into your question would have been far easier than providing a link to a picture of text...

Comment: If you look at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/ there is no "jammy" folder so this one is ros1. Go in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and delete the file that contains it. https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html says that ros2 should be using http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu

Comment: @user535733 Hmm really? There are so many ROS and APT questions here that I was just sorting through them to find the right duplicate target. Anyway, Thomas has already written an answer. I was going to use https://askubuntu.com/a/816505/1004020 , but the asker said they want ros2 not ros1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository settings are configuired to use ROS version 1 repositories.  Those are no longer up to date and do not support Ubuntu versions later than 20.04 - Jammy is 22.04.

You need to update the configuration for your repositories and use the ROS2 repositories - which use `http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu` instead of `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu`, and use ROS 2 instead of ROS 1.

You may want to refer to the ROS repository documentation here as well - https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html - to make sure you have the repository set up properly.

(I will expand to include those details once I'm at a computer, I'm on my tablet right now on my commute home from work)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, please let me know how do i change this to the link that you have provided.

Comment: @Gautham005 find where in your files under `/etc/apt/` contains the line 'packages.ros.org' in it, open in your favorite text editor (with sudo), change line, save file, run standard `apt update`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, It was of great help.

Comment: @Gautham005 glad to hear it!  Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved the issue!