# Choosing the Right ROS Distribution for Autonomous Vehicle Robotics Major

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, 23.04, ros

As a prospective robotics major with a keen interest in autonomous vehicles, I understand the significance of Robot Operating System (ROS) in this field. However, I'm unsure about which distribution of ROS would be most beneficial for my academic and career pursuits.

Considering ROS1 and ROS2, which distribution would be the most suitable for someone focused on autonomous vehicles? Would it be ROS 22.04, ROS 20.04, or 23.04?

Perception, SLAM and Sensors (LIDAR, IMU, GPS and ZED Cameras) are my main field for autonomous vehicles.I'm particularly interested in knowing about the compatibility, stability, and feature enhancements that each distribution offers, especially concerning autonomous vehicle applications. Additionally, any insights into the community support and potential future advancements in each version would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Comment: why do you assume it matters? the general consensus: always go for the highest LTS available if you need stability over a longer time. but that is valid for all software on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 or the 2023-April release is *END OF LIFE* thus would not be useful for anything online unless malware exploration is your intended purpose, with community support for it ended. The major differences between releases is the date on which they're released (20.04 = 2020.April, 22.04 = 2022.April) and thus when support ends (standard/community support is for 5 years, so 20.04 has months left, 22.04 has years)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ROS on BeagleBone Black?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816178/ros-on-beaglebone-black)